# Using Vault secrets in Kubernetes YAML

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, vault

I have a secret.yaml file with the below contents, but I would like to fetch the secrets from Hashicorp Vault. This secret.yaml is basically envoy configuration to setup OAuth for my application using Okta.

How can I fetch secret from Vault into my YAML? Could anybody please help me here.

secret.yaml

```
resources:
  - name: token
    generic_secret:
      secret:
        inline_bytes: "<my_token_secret>"
```

Comment: you can use https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way, but there is a nifty tool called [external-secrets](https://external-secrets.io/v0.5.7/).

[image: external-secret diagram]

It basically works like this. Once you have vault set up, you install external-secrets. Then, you create a `SecretStore` (works only on secrets in its own namespace) or a `ClusterSecretStore`(can create secrets cluster wide). Now, you create a CR called `ExternalSecret`, which references KV paths and properties in your vault:

```yaml
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: vault-example
spec:
  refreshInterval: "15s"
  secretStoreRef:
    name: vault-backend
    # Or ClusterSecretStore, depending on your setup
    kind: SecretStore
  target:
    name: example-sync
  data:
  - secretKey: username
    remoteRef:
      key: /secrets/dev
      property: user
  - secretKey: password
    remoteRef:
      key: /secrets/dev
      property: password
```

This will create a secret:

```yaml
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: example-sync
data:
  username: ...
  password: ...
```

hth